# taking tally of values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$record = array(Won,Lost,Won,Won,Lost);
```

I want to count the number of wins and losses in the array.

So everytime it finds "Won" in the array, do a $won++, and the same for loss, $loss++

I want to print out the record after that is completed.

```
print $won.' - '.$lost;
```

I think I figured it out, revisions to make this more efficient, will be appreciated.

```
<?php
$won = 0;
$lost = 0;

foreach ($record as $i => $value) {
  if($value == "Won") {
    $won++;
  } elseif($value == "Lost") {
    $lost++;
  }
}?>
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Have you looked at the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) statement?

Comment: My suggestion is just a more condensed version of yours. However, [zerkms's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869019/taking-tally-of-values-in-array/3869030#3869030) is probably the best (utilising a native PHP function, written in C, which should always be faster and less to code yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they constants, or did you forget to quote literal strings? I'm going to assume they are string literals.

Anyway, you could do

```
$won = $lost = 0;

foreach($record as $rec) {

    switch ($rec) {
        case 'Won':
            $won++;
            break;
        case 'Lost':
            $lost++;
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: That should be a colon between `$won++` and `$lost++`.

Comment: returns 2 wins and 2 losses, when it should be 2 wins and 1 loss (ignore the array values I used in the question)

Comment: @Alex Array ( [0] => Won [1] => Lost [2] => Not-Final [3] => Won )

Comment: @Brad You never mentioned there were others besides "Win" or "Loss". I'll make an edit to accommodate.

Comment: @Alex, sorry about that, still seems to get the win, loss count wrong, should be 2-1, your function produces 2-0

Comment: @Alex, nevermind, case 'Loss' should of been case 'Lost' - it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

[array_count_values()](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) is what you're looking for

```
$counts = array_count_values($record);
```

Comment: bravo!! Are we unable to change selected answers on stackoverflow?

Comment: @JustinP it is possible to do by the question author PS: oh my, 7 years passed

Comment: @Zerkms you cant win them all; however, this seems like one of the most black and white situations where the correct answer is chosen. The array_count_values() function is slick!!

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php set a callback, and you should be on your way

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$record = array('Won','Lost','Won','Won','Lost');
$won = 0;
$lost = 0;
foreach ($record as $stat) {
    switch($stat) {
        case 'Won':
                $won++;
                break;
        case 'Lost':
                $lost++;
                break;
    }
}
print $won.' - '.$lost;
?>
```